# Accessing Information From Vendor Database On The Basis Of Customer Query

Tags: database, plugin-recommendation

I am collecting data thru  gravity form on my website. On one side i am taking customer query, on other hand i have vendor database. On the basis of customer query i want to stretch information from vendor database and that i want to forward to that customer. How can i do that. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with gravity form plugin, but overall it should work as following:

1. Build a custom plugin which retrieves vendor database values.
2. Create a shortcode for plugin and integrate it into gravity form to retrieve values on the form.
3. Once required information is on the form, you should be able to forward it to gravity form by standard plugins function(as I sad, not familiar with plugin) or with cookie/JS.

Hope it helps.